# How to prevent a God model class in an MVC architecture?

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, dependency-injection, architecture, software-design

How can one prevent their model classes getting too large or depending on objects not directly related to them?

---

**Example**

Imagine a user registration form, that once successfully registered, the user receives an email to verify their email address.

**Sample code 1**

*disclaimer - this is demonstration code*

```
// route.js

app.post('/register', (req, res) => {
  container.get('UserController').postRegisterUser(req, res);
});
```

**Option 1 - adding emailSender dependency inside the User model**

```
// userController.js

class UserController {
  public constructor(model) {
    this.model = model;
  }

  public postRegisterUser(req, res) {
    const {email, password, repeatPassword} = req.body;
    const user = this.model.registerUser({email, password, repeatPassword});
    return res.render('/', user);
  }
}
```

```
// UserModel.ts

class UserModel {
  constructor(repository, validator, emailSender) {
    this.repository = repository;
    this.validator = validator;
    this.emailSender = emailSender;  // <--- emailSender injected in to model
  }

  public registerUser(user) {
    if (this.validator.isValid(user)) {
      this.repository.save(user);

      this.emailSender.sendVerificationEmail(user.email); // <---- emailSender called here

      return user;
    }
  }
}
```

**Option 2 - adding emailSender dependency inside the controller**

```
// userController.js

class UserController {
  public constructor(model, emailSender) {
    this.model = model;
    this.emailSender = emailSender;  // <--- Injected in constructor
  }

  public postRegisterUser(req, res) {
    const {email, password, repeatPassword} = req.body;
    const user = this.model.registerUser({email, password, repeatPassword});

    this.emailSender.sendVerificationEmail(email); // <--- emailSender called here

    return res.render('/', user);
  }
}
```

```
// UserModel.ts

// no EmailSender injected
class UserModel {
  constructor(repository, validator) {
    this.repository = repository;
    this.validator = validator;
  }

  public registerUser(user) {
    if (this.validator.isValid(user)) {
      this.repository.save(user);
      return user;
    }
  }
}
```

One can see how large these dependencies can become when other systems become involved - such as sending data to an S3 bucket, generating a csv file, etc. I ideally don't want my controller or model to have these dependencies, but then where do they go?

I imagine the ideal solution is something in-between these two options outlined above. I am just having difficulty with how to implement my web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build another component `UserProcessor` or `UserRegistrationProcessor`, which contains all those external calls to other services, and inject that component into `UserController`.

Comment: thats a good option, thanks. And perhaps the constructor could take in a `processorFactory` instead of passing it every processor the controller might depend on.